# Finding angle and direction between line segments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, computational-geometry, coordinate-system

I'm putting together a short demo on two things:

1. Finding the angle between two line segments and direction (right or left) as you travel counterclockwise around a shape
2. Using newer ecmascript syntax (e.g. .map, classes, const, let *(no vars)* backticks in console logging)

I'd like some feedback on whether the approach I've chosen for finding angles and directions is sound mathematically (I dislike demonstrating something that isn't decent logic). I know I could do without the Vector usage but am trying to explain to my audience relative vs. absolute coordinates, particularly when using atan2.

And feedback on the syntax/methods. Please bear in mind that since this is a demo, the code is verbose in output. (I purposely use console.warn for each angle just to make them easier to spot, so no comments on that are necessary :-)).

For this set of points, starting from the upper left-hand corner and working counterclockwise, the expected output is 45°, 45°, -90°, 45°, 45°, -90°.

[image: graph showing points]

There are two classes, a constant to convert between degrees/radians and a small dataset:

```
class Vector {

    constructor(x, y, z) {
        this.x = x || 0;
        this.y = y || 0;
        this.z = z || 0;
    }
}

class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x || 0;
        this.y = y || 0;
    }
}

const degRad = 180 / Math.PI;

const testCoordSet = [
    [-5, 15],
    [- 5, 0],
    [0, 5],
    [5, 0],
    [5, 15],
    [0, 10]
];
```

Then:

```
// Generate our test set of points - using map because we need to return a new collection
const testPts = testCoordSet.map(coord => new Point(coord[0], coord[1]));
console.log(testPts);

// Using forEach because we're not returning anything. In practice, further
//  operations could benefit from map because we can chain
testPts.forEach((pt, index, array) => {

    console.log(`\r\n${index}`);

    let pointA, pointC;

    const pointB = pt;

    // Determine which points will make up left, center and right points
    if (index === 0) { // If at beginning, left is the last point in the array

        pointA = array[array.length - 1];
        pointC = array[index + 1];

    } else if (index === array.length - 1) { // If at end, right is the first point in the array

        pointA = array[index - 1];
        pointC = array[0];

    } else {

        pointA = array[index - 1];
        pointC = array[index + 1];
    }

    const vectorAB = new Vector(pointA.x - pointB.x,
        pointA.y - pointB.y);

    const vectorCB = new Vector(pointC.x - pointB.x,
        pointC.y - pointB.y);

    console.log("vectorAB:", vectorAB);
    console.log("vectorCB:", vectorCB);

    // Stay in radians until the final result is calculated
    const absAngleABRad = Math.atan2(vectorAB.y, vectorAB.x);
    console.log(`absAngleABRad: ${absAngleABRad}`);

    const absAngleCBRad = Math.atan2(vectorCB.y, vectorCB.x);
    console.log(`absAngleCBRad: ${absAngleCBRad}`);

    const angularDiffRad = absAngleABRad - absAngleCBRad;
    console.log(`angularDiffRad: ${angularDiffRad}`);

    const angleDeg = angularDiffRad * degRad;
    console.warn(`angleDeg: ${angleDeg}`);
});
```

For comparison, I've thrown in a *traditional* for-next loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < testPts.length; i++) {

    console.log(`\r\n${i}`);

    let pointA, pointC;

    const pointB = testPts[i];

    // Determine which points will make up left, center and right points
    if (i === 0) { // If at beginning, left is the last point in the array

        pointA = testPts[testPts.length - 1];
        pointC = testPts[i + 1];

    } else if (i === testPts.length - 1) { // If at end, right is the first point in the array

        pointA = testPts[i - 1];
        pointC = testPts[0];

    } else {

        pointA = testPts[i - 1];
        pointC = testPts[i + 1];
    }

    const vectorAB = new Vector(pointA.x - pointB.x,
        pointA.y - pointB.y);

    const vectorCB = new Vector(pointC.x - pointB.x,
        pointC.y - pointB.y);

    console.log("vectorAB:", vectorAB);
    console.log("vectorCB:", vectorCB);

    // Stay in radians until the final result is calculated
    const absAngleABRad = Math.atan2(vectorAB.y, vectorAB.x);
    console.log(`absAngleABRad: ${absAngleABRad}`);

    const absAngleCBRad = Math.atan2(vectorCB.y, vectorCB.x);
    console.log(`absAngleCBRad: ${absAngleCBRad}`);

    const angularDiffRad = absAngleABRad - absAngleCBRad;
    console.log(`angularDiffRad: ${angularDiffRad}`);

    const angleDeg = angularDiffRad * degRad;
    console.warn(`angleDeg: ${angleDeg}`);
}
```

The complete, *updated* code may be found here:
https://gist.github.com/stonetip/e79254e001bda862119e97d7646e4c66

Comment: You should use `Array.forEach` not map.

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks for that suggestion. I've updated the code, comments and gist. It's an added bonus to be able to explain the difference between map and forEach when I demo this.

Answer (score 2):

#### Vector

The `z` is not needed. You are working exclusively in 2D, you Points are 2D, and it is never set or referenced. Get rid of it.

One addition I would make is to have an option to make the vector based on two point. Your class would then look like this

```
class Vector {
  constructor(a, b) {
    if(a instanceof Point && b instanceof Point) {
      this.x = b.x - a.x;
      this.y = b.y - a.y;
    }
    else {
      this.x = a || 0;
      this.y = b || 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I have renamed the arguments to make it easier to follow. You can then use it like this

```
const vectorAB = new Vector(pointA, pointB);
const vectorCB = new Vector(pointC, pointB);
```

#### Converting the angle

I would use a function to do this instead. What do you have to do with this constant value? Multiply with it? Add it? Divide with it? With a function you know what you've got. You put a value in, you get a value out. The name could also be a little more descriptive.

```
function degToRad(deg) {
  return deg * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

#### Rest parameters

If you want more ES6 you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) when generating your points.

```
const testPts = testCoordSet.map(coord => new Point(...coord));
```

#### DRY

When getting the right points you are repeating yourself a bit. The points are decided by a simple condition, so you can use a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
const pointA = array[index === 0 ? array.length-1 : index-1];
const pointB = pt;
const pointC = array[index === array.length-1 ? 0 : index+1];
```

Comment: Those are awesome suggestions to improve the code! Thanks for helping me learn. I really like the idea of having the Vector class accept either points or x,y vals. FYI, I have *z* in the class in case it's used with 3D code in the future.

Comment: For even more ES6 you could use default parameters for the constructor: `constructor(a = 0, b = 0)` whereby simplifying the assignment later on: `this.x = a; this.y = b;`.